# Do has_many :through associations work for models that only exist in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

for

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, :through => :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :c
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end
```

If i bring up a rails console, and do

```
a = A.new
b = a.bs.build
b.c = C.new
```

Then i get

```
a.cs => []
```

but

```
a.bs[0].c => c
```

If a is saved, then it all works. Is this expected? why doesn't the through association work when the models only exist in memory? thanks

Comment: Perhaps, the association is 'established' when object is saved (or loaded), not created. Is it mandatory that you operate with unsaved instances?

Comment: Its not, but i prefer to have as small a footprint as possible when running my tests, if they can be run in memory, i will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that object `a` has no reference to object `c` created. Normally it would run a query, but it won't since it is not saved to db. I think that it is created for db relations and it just doesn't check references to in-memory objects.

You can also try this:

```
a = A.new
a.cs.build
a.bs
=> []
```

but

```
a.cs
=> [created c object]
```

Comment: Another sad side effect of ActiveRecord's entwinement of model and persistence. Rails and AR make me happy most of the time, but now I am sad. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I worked around it:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs

  def cs
    bs.map &:c
  end

end
```

You might lose something. For example, `cs` is now read-only so you can't assign to it or `build` or `create` on it. That's fine in my particular case because I will always mutate `bs` only, which is maybe a better practice. Also many-to-many objects like `B` will normally have some attributes that you want to set.

By the way, if `C` is joined to `B` by `has_many` instead of `belongs_to` change the above code to use `flat_map` instead of `map`.